# How do I transpose rows to columns in a array of values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, transpose

My data structure looks like this:

```
var data = [
    { 
    A:[
    {name: 'Test1', amount: 20},
    {name: 'Test2', amount: 30}
    ], 
    B:[
    {name: 'Test3', amount: 40},
    {name: 'Test4', amount: 50}
    ] 
    },
    {
    A:[
    {name: 'Test1', amount: 200},
    {name: 'Test2', amount: 300}
    ], 
    B:[
    {name: 'Test3', amount: 400},
    {name: 'Test4', amount: 500}
    ]}
  ]
```

Here is how I would like to transpose my structure:
[image]

I also created my array structure in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rj5e38v9/3/

Comment: check update answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array reduce and create a object with keys `A` & `B`.
Then you can iterate this object to create the table

```js
var data = [{
    A: [{
        name: 'Test1',
        amount: 20
      },
      {
        name: 'Test2',
        amount: 30
      }
    ],
    B: [{
        name: 'Test3',
        amount: 40
      },
      {
        name: 'Test4',
        amount: 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    A: [{
        name: 'Test1',
        amount: 200
      },
      {
        name: 'Test2',
        amount: 300
      }
    ],
    B: [{
        name: 'Test3',
        amount: 400
      },
      {
        name: 'Test4',
        amount: 500
      }
    ]
  }
]

const val = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for (let keys in curr) {
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
      acc[keys] = [];
    }
    acc[keys].push(...curr[keys])

  }
  return acc;
}, {});

let tableStr = ''
for (let keys in val) {
  tableStr += `<ul>
  <li class="headerList">${keys}</li>
  ${val[keys].map(elem=>{return '<li><span>'+elem.name+'<span class="valCol">'+elem.amount+'</span></li>'})}
  
 </ul>`
}


document.getElementById('dataDisplay').innerHTML = tableStr
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none
}

.valCol {
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: green;
}

.headerList {
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dataDisplay">


</div>
```